# Zend Paginator 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

So I'm using ZF with doctrine, and I'm trying to use pagination like this:

```
    $d =  Zend_Paginator::factory($this->items->displayItems(['page' => 1]),'Array');
    $d->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
    var_dump($d->getPages());
```

But `I need a way to set the total count of the pages for the paginator` because the array that I'm passing is always going to contain 10 items per page, is there a way to do this? I need this in order for the paginator to work, because right now is displaying this:

```
object(stdClass)#285 (12) { ["pageCount"]=> int(1) ["itemCountPerPage"]=> int(10) ["first"]=> int(1) ["current"]=> int(1) ["last"]=> int(1) ["pagesInRange"]=> array(1) { [1]=> int(1) } ["firstPageInRange"]=> int(1) ["lastPageInRange"]=> int(1) ["currentItemCount"]=> int(10) ["totalItemCount"]=> int(10) ["firstItemNumber"]=> int(1) ["lastItemNumber"]=> int(10) }
```

As you can see the `pageCount` is 1 and I have over 100 items in the table.

I didn't find any methods like `->setToalPagesCount()` for the paginator, is there a way to set something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to set items per page this is the method :

```
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage( ItemsPerPage );
```

Comment: No, count total I did found a solution and I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a solution and the solution was to create my own paginator adapter and add the `setCount` method so this way I could provide the total count. You can use what namespace you like I had `Bisna` so the path is: `library\Bisna\Application\Paginator\Array`

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework
 *
 * LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
 * with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@zend.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Paginator
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 * @version    $Id$
 */

/**
 * @see Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface
 */
require_once 'Zend/Paginator/Adapter/Interface.php';

/**
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Paginator
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class Bisna_Application_Paginator_Array implements Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface
{
    /**
     * Array
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_array = null;

    /**
     * Item count
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $_count = null;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param array $array Array to paginate
     */
    public function __construct(array $array)
    {
        $this->_array = $array;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of items for a page.
     *
     * @param  integer $offset Page offset
     * @param  integer $itemCountPerPage Number of items per page
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
    {
        return array_slice($this->_array, $offset, $itemCountPerPage);
    }

    /**
     * @param $count
     */
    public function setCount($count){
        $this->_count = $count;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the total number of rows in the array.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function count()
    {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

So now I have the `setCount()` method, the way you will use this is:

```
$adapter = new Bisna_Application_Paginator_Array($this->items->list('pass arguments with the active page number'));
$adapter->setCount(1000); //maybe use another query from db here to calculate the total amount of pages
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
```